I want to set the adc value to 0 when I read the adc value with ads1115 and it's not connected, but the adc value is read
I'm reading the adc value with ads1115 and outputting the sensor value
If you read the value well and convert the voltage, the desired value is coming out
​
But I intentionally took out the sensor and tried to use the sensor value as zero when it was in this state
At this time, the adc value is 5750-5850
When connecting, the adc value goes from 2000 to 14,000 degrees
There are a lot of values that I read when I'm not connected. 5780, 5768, 5805... It comes out in a variety of ways
​
When it's not connected, if there are 1 or 2 adc values, you can just give up about 2 sensor values and treat them as an error as shown below
There are so many adc prices that go back and forth. Is there a good way to distinguish them?
I don't think it's possible to cover all of that range
int16_t iAdcValue = ADS1X15_readADC(&hads1115, ADS1X15_READ_1);
            if ((iAdcValue < 0 || iAdcValue == 12827 || iAdcValue == 12786) == 0) {
              fAdc = iAdcValue;
              ADS1X15_toVoltage(&hads1115, fAdc);
            }

int16_t ADS1X15_readADC(ADS1X15 *ads, uint16_t readmode) {
    ADS1X15_requestADC(ads, readmode);
    uint32_t start = HAL_GetTick();
    uint32_t timeout = (128 >> (ads->datarate >> 5)) + 1; // 적절한 타임아웃 계산

    if (ads->mode == ADS1X15_MODE_SINGLE) {
        while (ADS1X15_isBusy(ads)) {
            if ((HAL_GetTick() - start) > timeout) {
                // 타임아웃 발생, 에러 처리
                return ADS1X15_ERROR_TIMEOUT;
            }
        }
    } else {
        HAL_Delay(ads->conversionDelay); // 변환 지연 시간
    }

    int16_t value = ADS1X15_getValue(ads);
    return value;
}


float ADS1X15_toVoltage(ADS1X15* ads, int16_t value) {
    if (value == 0) return 0.0f;

    float volts = ADS1X15_getMaxVoltage(ads);
    if (volts < 0) return volts;

    volts *= value;
    if (ads->config & ADS_CONF_RES_16) {
        volts /= 32767.0f;
    } else {
        volts /= 2047.0f;
    }
    return volts;
}

float ADS1X15_getMaxVoltage(ADS1X15* ads) {
    switch (ads->gain) {
        case ADS1X15_PGA_6_144V: return 6.144f;
        case ADS1X15_PGA_4_096V: return 4.096f;
        case ADS1X15_PGA_2_048V: return 2.048f;
        case ADS1X15_PGA_1_024V: return 1.024f;
        case ADS1X15_PGA_0_512V: return 0.512f;
        case ADS1X15_PGA_0_256V: return 0.256f;
        default: ads->error = ADS1X15_INVALID_VOLTAGE; return ads->error;
    }
}

I made this for your information
https://github.com/RobTillaart/ADS1X15/blob/master/ADS1X15.cpp
